# ggplot2: Logistic Regression - plot probabilities and regression line

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression

I have a data.frame containing a continuous predictor and a dichotomous response variable.

```
> head(df)
  position response
1        0        1
2        3        1
3       -4        0
4       -1        0
5       -2        1
6        0        0
```

I can easily compute a logistic regression by means of the `glm()`-function, no problems up to this point.

Next, **I want to create a plot with `ggplot`, that contains both the empiric probabilities** for each of the overall 11 predictor values, **and the fitted regression line**.

I went ahead and computed the probabilities with `cast()` and saved them in another data.frame

```
> probs
   position   prob
1        -5 0.0500
2        -4 0.0000
3        -3 0.0000
4        -2 0.2000
5        -1 0.1500
6         0 0.3684
7         1 0.4500
8         2 0.6500
9         3 0.7500
10        4 0.8500
11        5 1.0000
```

I plotted the probabilities:

```
p <- ggplot(probs, aes(x=position, y=prob)) + geom_point()
```

But when I try to add the fitted regression line

```
p <- p + stat_smooth(method="glm", family="binomial", se=F)
```

it returns a warning: `non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!`. 
I know that in order to plot the `stat_smooth` "correctly", I'd have to call it on the original `df` data with the dichotomous variable. However if I use the `df`data in `ggplot()`, I see no way to plot the probabilities.

**How can I combine the probabilities and the regression line in one plot**, in the way it's meant to be in ggplot2, i.e. without getting any warning or error messages?

Comment: Plot the data and the `+stat_smooth` first, and then add the line plot for the probabilities  you want with a call to: `+geom_line(aes(x=position, y=prob), data=probs)`. Untested in the absence of a data example.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There are basically three solutions:

### Merging the data.frames

The easiest, after you have your data in two separate `data.frame`s would be to merge them by `position`:

```
mydf <- merge( mydf, probs, by="position")
```

Then you can call `ggplot` on this `data.frame` without warnings:

```
ggplot( mydf, aes(x=position, y=prob)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "glm", 
    method.args = list(family = "binomial"), 
    se = FALSE)
```

[image]

### Avoiding the creation of two data.frames

In future you could directly avoid the creation of two separate data.frames which you have to merge later. Personally, I like to use the `plyr` package for that:

```
librayr(plyr)
mydf <- ddply( mydf, "position", mutate, prob = mean(response)  )
```

### Edit: Use different data for each layer

I forgot to mention, that you can use for each layer another `data.frame` which is a strong advantage of `ggplot2`:

```
ggplot( probs, aes(x=position, y=prob)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(data = mydf, aes(x = position, y = response),
    method = "glm", method.args = list(family = "binomial"), 
    se = FALSE)
```

As an additional hint: Avoid the usage of the variable name `df` since you override the built in function `stats::df` by assigning to this variable name.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The second alternative seems pretty elegant. I guess I have to delve into the `plyr` package a bit. Seems pretty useful!

Comment: This code no longer works. `Error: Unknown parameters: family`. One has to use `stat_smooth(method="glm", se=F, method.args = list(family="binomial"))`. The `...` passes the family parameter to the layer, not the method.